# Reversing a doubly linked list in C

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm currently trying to reverse a doubly-linked list and print it out in C. Unfortunately, my code is only printing one item and I have no idea why. I have looked at multiple solutions on Stack Overflow and online

Basically, I pass a txt file that looks like this.

```
Name 100
John 40
```

Here's the full code:

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    typedef struct person{
      char* firstName;  
      char* age;
      struct person* previous; 
      struct person* next; 
    }Person;
    
    void print(Person*);
    
    void reverseList(Person*);
    
    Person* add (Person*, char*, char*);
    
    void print (Person* list) {
      while(list != NULL) {
        printf("%s %s\n",list->firstName,list->age);
        list = list->next;
      }
    }
    
    void reverseList (Person* list) {
      Person *current = list;
      Person* last = current;
    
      while(current != NULL) {
        Person *temp = NULL;
        temp = current->previous; 
        current->previous = current->next;
        current->next = temp;
        last = current;
        current = current->previous;
      }
      list = last;
    
      while(list != NULL) {
        printf("%s %s\n",list->firstName,list->age);
        list = list->next;
      }
    }
    
    Person* add (Person *list, char *firstName, char *age) {
      // allocate node
      Person* node = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));
    
      // if node is empty
      if(node != NULL) {
        node->firstName=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(firstName)+1);
        
        // insert name
        strcpy(node->firstName, firstName);
    
        // allocate age & insert
        node->age = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(age)+1);
        strcpy(node->age, age);
        node->next = NULL;
    
        if(list == NULL) list = node;
        else {
          Person *curr = list;
          Person *pre = NULL;
          while(curr != NULL) {
            if(strcmp(curr->firstName, firstName) > 0) {
              if(pre == NULL) {
                node->next = list;
                list = node;
              } else {
                pre->next = node;
                node->next = curr;
              }
              return list;
            }
            pre = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
          }
          pre->next = node;
        }
        return list;
      }
      return list;
    }
    
    int main (int argc, char **argv) {
      FILE *in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
      char name[20];
      char num[20];
      Person *list=NULL;
     
      while(fscanf(in, "%s %s",name, num)==2) {
        list = add(list,name, num);
      }
    
      printf ("Original List\n***\n");
      print (list);
      
      printf ("Printing Reversed List\n***\n");
      reverseList(list);
      
      return 0;
    }
```

The goal is, if I pass a list like:

```
John 10
Mary 5
```

It would print

```
Mary 5
John 10
```

Any idea what's going on here? Not sure what I am misunderstanding

Comment: Doesn't the address of the head node changes during the reversal? (e.g. `list = last;`)  If you pass a pointer by value, you can't make that change. (the change is lost on function return) You need to pass the address of the pointer so the pointer at that address can be updated in your function. `void reverseList (Person **list)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Forgot to mention, I can't really change the function prototypes, unfortunately, but I did try that anyway and didn't have any success..

Comment: In order to help further, we need [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see how your list is filled, how the end nodes are terminated and how your reversal is called, etc..

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Just did what you wanted I think, hope it helps.

Comment: @TomServo This data structure wasn't something I chose, I was presented with it and was told to reverse the list given the surrounding code.

Comment: @ilovehatecoding, you issue isn't in your `refereseList()` function (which doesn't actually reverse the list). Rather all it does is iterate to the end of the list swapping pointers (unnecessarily) and then ***prints*** the list in reverse order (not the same as reversing a list). All you need to do is iterate to the end node and traverse the list using the `previous` pointer to print in reverse. You problem with that is your `add()` function not setting the `previous` pointer correctly. (it doesn't set any of them). When you attempt the reverse print, you print the last node only.

Comment: Write a `prn_ptrs (Person *list) { while (list) { printf ("%p  %p  %p\n", (void*)list->previous, (void*)list, (void*)list->next); list = list->next; } }` function and after you print your original list, add `puts ("Pointers\n***");` and `prn_ptrs (list);` and check... You will see all your previous pointers are `(nil)` - unset. In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: @ilovehatecoding Perhaps the (Instructor?) is looking for someone wise enough to suggest the *right* answer.  Actually reversing the list is actually the *worst* way to achieve the expected results.  Doesn't matter if you "chose" it or not.  If I gave this assignment, say in a coding test, during an interview, any candidate who actually reversed the pointers in the list would immediately fail.  The candidate who simply traversed it backwards would move to the front of the pack due to **thinking about the requirement**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in my comments, your problems wasn't in your `reverseList()` function (although it needed help), your problem was in your `add()` function not setting any of the `previous` node pointers. So when you got to the end of your list and attempted to print the list in reverse, all you printed was the current node and your print-loop would exit because the `->next` node (original `->previous` node) was `NULL`.

To fix the problem, you need to wire-up the `->previous` pointers.

(**Edit** `add()` rewritten to address sort error on corner cases in original)

```
Person *add (Person *list, char *firstName, char *age)
{
  size_t len;
  Person *node = malloc (sizeof *node),   /* allocate node, use dereference ptr for size */
         *iter = list,
         *prev = NULL;

  if (!node) {                            /* validate EVERY allocation */
    perror ("malloc-node");
    return list;
  }
  node->next = node->previous = NULL;     /* initialize next and previous NULL */

  len = strlen (firstName);                         /* get length of firstName */
  if (!(node->firstName = malloc (len + 1))) {      /* allocate/validate */
    perror ("malloc-node->firstName");
    free (node);                                    /* free node before return */
    return list;
  }
  memcpy (node->firstName, firstName, len + 1);     /* copy firstName to node */

  len = strlen (age);                               /* get length of age */
  if (!(node->age = malloc (len + 1))) {            /* allocate/validate */
    perror ("malloc-node->age");
    free (node->firstName);                         /* free node->firstName, and */
    free (node);                                    /* free node before return */
    return list;
  }
  memcpy (node->age, age, len + 1);                 /* copy age to node */

  if (!list)                              /* if list empty */
    return node;                          /* return node */

  /* iterate until iter->firstName sorts before firstName */
  while (iter && strcmp (firstName, iter->firstName) <= 0) {
    prev = iter;
    iter = iter->next;
  }

  if (!iter) {                            /* if new end node */
    prev->next = node;
    node->previous = prev;
  }
  else {                                  /* insert between nodes */
    node->next = iter->next;
    node->previous = iter;
    if (iter->next)                       /* protect when new next to last */
      iter->next->previous = node;
    iter->next = node;
  }

  /* if new first node, return iter, otherwise return list */
  return strcmp (list->firstName, firstName) >= 0 ? node : list;
}
```

Your `reverseList()` cannot actually **"reverse"** anything. All it can do is iterate to the last node in the list and then print the list in reverse order using the `->previous` pointers. As such, you are needlessly swapping pointers. Simply iterate to the end, turn-around and use the `->previous` pointers to iterate back to the beginning printing the list in reverse, e.g.

```
void reverseList (Person *list) {

  if (!list) {                  /* validate list not empty */
    puts ("(list empty)");
    return;
  }
  
  while (list->next != NULL)    /* iterte to last node */
    list = list->next;

  while (list) {    /* print in reverse using ->previous pointers */
    printf ("%s %s\n", list->firstName, list->age);
    list = list->previous;
  }
}
```

It is unfortunate you cannot change the function prototypes. To actually reverse the lined list in a `void` function, you must pass the address of the list pointer so the node at that address can be updated with the new first node. If you did want to actually reverse the list, you could do:

```
void reverseList (Person **list) {
  
  Person *current = *list;
  Person *last = current;
  
  if (!current || !current->next)
    return;
  
  do {
    Person *temp = current->previous; 
    current->previous = current->next;
    current->next = temp;
    last = current;
  } while ((current = current->previous));
  *list = last;
}
```

You would call the above as: `reverseList(&list);`. Then you would simply call `print (list);` again to print the list in reverse....

Further, if you could change the prototypes and pass the address of the list pointer to your `add()` function, you would eliminate the need to keep track of `pre` and `curr`, you could simply iterate using both the address of the current node and a pointer to the current node. See [Linus on Understanding Pointers](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/)

Lastly, do not forget to free the memory you allocate. You must free `firstName` and `age` before freeing the node. A simple delete list function to delete all currently allocated memory associated with a list could be written as:

```
/** delete all nodes in list */
void del_list (Person *list)
{
    while (list) {
        Person *victim = list;
        list = list->next;
        free (victim->firstName);
        free (victim->age);
        free (victim);
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

---

**Full Example**

Since the link I provided to the example code in the comments is only good for a month, I'll include the example here for posterity. The example is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct person{
  char* firstName;  
  char* age;
  struct person* previous; 
  struct person* next; 
}Person;

void print(Person*);

// void reverseList(Person*);

Person* add (Person*, char*, char*);

void print (Person* list) {
  while(list != NULL) {
    printf("%s %s\n",list->firstName,list->age);
    list = list->next;
  }
}

void prnptrs (Person *list) {
    while (list) {
        printf ("%p  %p  %p\n", (void*)list->previous, (void*)list, (void*)list->next);
        list = list->next;
    }
}
#ifndef PASSPTR2PTR
void reverseList (Person *list) {

  if (!list) {                  /* validate list not empty */
    puts ("(list empty)");
    return;
  }
  
  while (list->next != NULL)    /* iterte to last node */
    list = list->next;

  while (list) {    /* print in reverse using ->previous pointers */
    printf ("%s %s\n", list->firstName, list->age);
    list = list->previous;
  }
}
#else
void reverseList (Person **list) {
  
  Person *current = *list;
  Person *last = current;
  
  if (!current || !current->next)
    return;
  
  do {
    Person *temp = current->previous; 
    current->previous = current->next;
    current->next = temp;
    last = current;
  } while ((current = current->previous));
  *list = last;
}
#endif

Person *add (Person *list, char *firstName, char *age)
{
  size_t len;
  Person *node = malloc (sizeof *node),   /* allocate node, use dereference ptr for size */
         *iter = list,
         *prev = NULL;

  if (!node) {                            /* validate EVERY allocation */
    perror ("malloc-node");
    return list;
  }
  node->next = node->previous = NULL;     /* initialize next and previous NULL */

  len = strlen (firstName);                         /* get length of firstName */
  if (!(node->firstName = malloc (len + 1))) {      /* allocate/validate */
    perror ("malloc-node->firstName");
    free (node);                                    /* free node before return */
    return list;
  }
  memcpy (node->firstName, firstName, len + 1);     /* copy firstName to node */

  len = strlen (age);                               /* get length of age */
  if (!(node->age = malloc (len + 1))) {            /* allocate/validate */
    perror ("malloc-node->age");
    free (node->firstName);                         /* free node->firstName, and */
    free (node);                                    /* free node before return */
    return list;
  }
  memcpy (node->age, age, len + 1);                 /* copy age to node */

  if (!list)                              /* if list empty */
    return node;                          /* return node */

  /* iterate until iter->firstName sorts before firstName */
  while (iter && strcmp (firstName, iter->firstName) <= 0) {
    prev = iter;
    iter = iter->next;
  }

  if (!iter) {                            /* if new end node */
    prev->next = node;
    node->previous = prev;
  }
  else {                                  /* insert between nodes */
    node->next = iter->next;
    node->previous = iter;
    if (iter->next)                       /* protect when new next to last */
      iter->next->previous = node;
    iter->next = node;
  }

  /* if new first node, return iter, otherwise return list */
  return strcmp (list->firstName, firstName) >= 0 ? node : list;
}

/** delete all nodes in list */
void del_list (Person *list)
{
    while (list) {
        Person *victim = list;
        list = list->next;
        free (victim->firstName);
        free (victim->age);
        free (victim);
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  FILE *in = argc > 1 ? fopen(argv[1], "r") : stdin;
  char name[20];
  char num[20];
  Person *list=NULL;
 
  while(fscanf(in, "%s %s",name, num)==2) {
    list = add(list,name, num);
  }
  fclose (in);

  printf ("Original List\n***\n");
  print (list);
  puts ("\nPointers\n***");
  prnptrs (list);
  
  printf ("\nPrinting Reversed List\n***\n");
#ifndef PASSPTR2PTR
  reverseList(list);
#else
  reverseList(&list);
  print (list);
#endif
  del_list (list);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Both versions of (1) your printing the list in reverse, and (2) actually reversing the list are conditionally included by the define of `PASSPTR2PTR`. If not defined, it will simply pass a pointer to list print the list in reverse, If `PASSPTR2PTR` is defined, it will pass the address of the list pointer and perform the actual list reversal.

The test data file you posted on pastebin was:

```
$ cat dat/ypzgttvk.txt
John 12345
Sam 54321
Lion 43222
```

In both cases the output will be:

```
$ ./bin/lld_reverse_add dat/ypzgttvk.txt
Original List
***
John 12345
Lion 43222
Sam 54321

Pointers
***
(nil)  0xb014a0  0xb01580
0xb014a0  0xb01580  0xb01510
0xb01580  0xb01510  (nil)

Printing Reversed List
***
Sam 54321
Lion 43222
John 12345
```

Which shows the original list, the addresses from all `previous current next` nodes for each node in the list and finally the output of the list reversed.

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Wouldn't passing the address of the pointer require the function to be void, so I wouldn't be able to return the list?

Comment: No, your other option, much like `add()` is to return `Person*`, then you can pass `Person *list` as the parameter and return the new 1st node and assign that to `list` in `main()`. If you note I have removed all of your assignments within `reverseList()` as they were only changing the copy of the pointer local to `reverseList()`. Those changes are lost on the function return. So if you want the actual reversal, you must either (1) pass the address of the list pointer and update what is at that address; or (2) change the return type to `Person*` and return the new 1st node to assign.

Comment: Ahh thanks for the clarification. I did try running the above code, although I am getting a segmentation fault which I think is related to the add function. Not sure what's going on there

Comment: Here is a working example of your code [Double Linked-List Reverse](https://paste.opensuse.org/58862582). It has both cases (printing in reverse, and passing address of list). Compile normally for your case, add `-DPASSPTR2PTR` to your compiler options to compile with the code passing the address of the list. Output for both is the same. Whenever you pass a `-D...` (define) it is the same as including `#define PASSPTR2PTR` at the top of the code. You are just defining a constant. It allows you to conditionally compile code in the same source.

Comment: Very strange, compiling normally using "gcc -o reversepractice main.c -Wall -g -I." and running like ./reversepractice names.txt and I'm still facing a Segmentation fault, odd

Comment: That tells me your input file is corrupt and likely contains either UTF-16 characters or other maladies. The code above not only compiles without a single warning using `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -std=c11 -Ofast`, the memory use/error check with `valgrind` shows all memory freed and `"ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)"` The file above works regardless of whether you have Unix or DOS line endings.

Comment: Copy paste my `joe.txt` file above and see if the problem remains.

Comment: That's really strange
Is this why it doesn't work with a test case like [this](https://pastebin.com/ypzgttvk)?

Comment: Ahah, -- yes that is your `add()` function. Let me look further at the sort. As mentioned, you should really provide `Person**` so you can iterate with the address of the pointer, but I understand your prototypes are fixed.

Comment: Yeah I understand how it would be a lot more efficient, I wish I could haha, but unfortunately I have to do it this way - and sure, I appreciate it!

Comment: I found the issue. I apologize, your nested logic was very hard to follow -- so I just rewrote it. All of this is made 10 times harder than it needs to be if you simply pass the address of the pointer. The `add()` code can be reduced by almost 1/2.

Answer (score 0):

The code actually seems to be working fine. I'm thinking your test case is not coded correctly, perhaps you forgot to set `mary->previous = john` (or `john->next = mary`)

I ran

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct person{
  char *firstName;  
  int age; 
  struct person *previous;
  struct person *next;
}Person;

void reverseList (Person *list) {
  Person* current = list;
  Person* last = current;

  while(current != NULL) {
    Person* temp = NULL;
    temp = current->previous;
    current->previous = current->next;
    current->next = temp;
    last = current;
    current = current->previous;
  }
  list = last;

  while(list != NULL) {
    printf("%s %d\n",list->firstName,list->age);
    list = list->next;
  }
}


int main(void) {
    struct person *john = (struct person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));
    struct person *mary = (struct person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));
    john->next = mary;
    mary->previous = john;

    john->age = 10;
    john->firstName = "john";

    mary->age = 5;
    mary->firstName = "mary";

    reverseList(john);

}
```

and the result was

```
mary 5
john 10
```