# I understand that there is no need for a variable to store the prev node in the doubly linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

so I use cur->llink when I search the node to express previous node, and delete the node.
Suppose erase a node in the middle.

```
cur=h->first;
cur->llink=NULL;
while(cur->rlink!=NULL)
{
    if(I find the node that delete(cur))
    {
        cur->llink->rllink=cur->rllink;
        cur->rlink->llink=cur->llink;
        free(cur);
    }

    cur->llink=cur;
    cur=cur->rlink;
}
```

but when I print the list. The node I free is still on the list for garbage value.
ex) [0]=10, [1]=34321321, [2]=30

I want this: [0]=10, [1]=30.
so I use prev node. make prev node and just replace cur->llink to prev like singly-linked-list.
then It works.
I don't know why it works

Comment: What is `cur->llink=cur;` for? (it is wiping out your previous node link) `cur` after `cur=cur->rlink;` should have a valid `cur->llink` that points to what was `cur` before `cur=cur->rlink;`. You may find a recent answer to [Reversing a doubly linked list in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66997713/3422102) helpful. (you can ignore the "Reversing" part in the title, it is a generic doubly-linked list discussion)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin So, do I need to put cur->llink in the prev variable?

Comment: When you add a node to your list, you establish that `llink` and `rlink` point to the previous and next nodes in the list (with `head->llink = NULL;` on the first node and `tail->rlink = NULL` on the last). When you iterate to find the node to remove, you do not adjust any pointers except when actually preforming the removal. The code `cur=cur->rlink;` sets the current node to the next node. That is all you need to iterate over your list. The `cur->llink=cur;` doesn't belong in the function at all. (see this edited comment)

Comment: Here is a simple doubly-linked list (of integers) example that shows you the list operations and how to find and delete a node in the list (the code randomly deletes all nodes in the list as a validation test) See [Doubly-Linked List of Integers - Remove Rand Nodes Check](https://pastebin.com/E6WpPjTC)

Comment: Please provide the code that initialises the list, and then calls this function and then prints the list, so we can run and see what you are saying.